# Error building mpi2 - trouble linking libboost_system

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, mpi

I am trying to build mpi2 and encounter the following error during make:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/env.dir/env.cc.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/local/boost-1.56.0/lib/libboost_system.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The cmake command I used prior to running make was:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=NativeRelease ../ -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost-1.56.0/ -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/usr/local/boost-1.56.0/include -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/local/boost-1.56.0/lib`

I have tried linking against libboost_system.so, but I'm unsure how to do this with cmake (I tried adding `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-lboost_system"` to the cmake command, but this had no effect).

How do I correctly link this with cmake to resolve this error?

Comment: What MPI2? OpenMPI, MPICH or anything else? MPI is just the protocol.   Clear your build directory and re-run CMake. What does configuration state? Does it find boost or is any other component missing? Is your boost version recent enough?

Comment: Thanks @usr1234567 for the reply. MPI2 as implemented here: [link](https://github.com/uma-pi1/mpi2). Clearing and rerunning gave the same result. The configuration output was: `-- Build type: NativeRelease
-- Boost version: 1.56.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
--   mpi
--   thread
--   program_options
--   regex
--   filesystem
--   chrono
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done`
Does it normally output an error if it can't find a library?

Comment: Hav you installed MPICH as described in the install instructions? "2. Install mpich2 (>= 1.3.2p1)." I don' think it is complete MPI implmentiontation, its just a wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I've followed all the steps and I believe it has installed correctly (I've attempted this installation on 3 separate machines).

Comment: Your operating system and compiler information is absolutely required in order to debug compilation problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be that Boost.System isn't listed as a requirement in the CMakeLists.txt.

Looking at https://github.com/uma-pi1/mpi2/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L67, it seems like `system` should be added immediately after `chrono` in the `find_package(Boost ...)` call.